# How can I handle blocks of an input file individually?

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to read a firewall config and manipulate the objects it defines using Python to then change the object name and export that to a new config file. Example of the input:

```
edit "host1"
  set subnet 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.255  
next
edit "host2"
  set subnet 10.0.0.11 255.255.255.255 
next
```

When reading the file I need a way to then iterate through every instance of "edit [...]" with the following attributes being set (which can be more than one). In essence, a line containing "edit" means the start of a new object and "next" means the end of said object. The goal is to check the contents of each object and rename it based on what it is, based on the previous example the output would be:

```
edit "10.0.0.10"
  set subnet 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.255  
next
edit "10.0.0.11"
  set subnet 10.0.0.11 255.255.255.255 
next
```

Manipulating the text itself shouldn't be too much of an issue, but I'm currently stuck at finding a way to treat each block of the config individually.

I thought about converting the input to XML and then use ElementTree, but am hoping that there's a more elegant way of doing it without that extra step that I'm just not seeing due to lack of programming experience.

Thanks in advance for any inputs on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive descent parser time!

If these config files really are that simple, you can use this grammar:

```
start: block*
block: EDIT HOSTNAME rule* NEXT
HOSTNAME: /"[^"]"/
rule: SET SUBNET IP IP
IP: /\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/
```

Then the parser would look like this. It automatically rewrites all `edit` blocks using the host from the `set` rule.

```
import re


class Parser:
    def __init__(self, tokens: list):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def _next(self) -> str:
        token = self.tokens[0]
        del self.tokens[0]

        return token

    def _peek(self) -> str:
        return self.tokens[0]

    def consume(self, value: str) -> str:
        token = self._next()

        if token == value:
            return token

        raise SyntaxError(f"Could not consume {value!r} given {token!r} + {self.tokens}")

    def consume_regex(self, regex) -> str:
        token = self._next()

        match, = regex.fullmatch(token).groups()

        return match

    def parse(self):
        edits = self.parse_start()

        assert not self.tokens

        return edits

    def parse_start(self):
        "start: edit*"

        edits = []

        while self.tokens:
            edit = self.parse_edit()
            edits.append(edit)

        return edits

    def parse_edit(self) -> str:
        "edit: EDIT HOST rule NEXT"

        HOST_REGEX = re.compile(r'^"([^"]*)"$')

        _EDIT = self.consume('edit')
        _HOST = self.consume_regex(HOST_REGEX)
        _rule = self.parse_rule()
        _NEXT = self.consume('next')

        # REWRITE HERE!
        rewritten = f'''
{_EDIT} "{_rule['IP']}"
    {_rule['type']} {_rule['subnet']} {_rule['IP']} {_rule['mask']}
{_NEXT}
        '''.strip()

        return rewritten


    def parse_rule(self) -> dict:
        "rule: SET rule_set"  # other rules can be added
        tok = self._peek()

        if tok == 'set':
            return self.parse_rule_set()

        raise SyntaxError(f'Unknown rule {tok!r}')

    def parse_rule_set(self) -> dict:
        "rule_set: SET SUBNET IP MASK"

        # this regex doesn't check the validity of the IP address,
        # but it's good enough here
        IP_REGEX = re.compile(r"^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$")

        _SET = self.consume('set')
        _SUBNET = self.consume('subnet')
        _IP = self.consume_regex(IP_REGEX)
        _MASK = self.consume_regex(IP_REGEX)

        return {'type': 'set', 'subnet': _SUBNET, 'IP': _IP, 'mask': _MASK}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = '''
edit "host1"
  set subnet 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.255  
next
edit "host2"
  set subnet 10.0.0.11 255.255.255.255 
next
    '''

    ret = Parser(data.split()).parse()

    print('\n'.join(ret))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py
edit "10.0.0.10"
    set subnet 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.255
next
edit "10.0.0.11"
    set subnet 10.0.0.11 255.255.255.255
next
$
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax is pretty simple overall, but there are different commands to define the object (example only contains hosts, other types are also possible but the common factor is that each object starts with "edit [name]" and ends with "next"
I'll look into how I can adapt this to fit the other use cases.